# How can I install qpdf on Mac 10.8.3?

Tags: macos, r, installation, package

When running `R CMD check` on packages on a Mac build server, I'm getting a warning

```
â€˜qpdfâ€™ is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
```

I can't seem to get [qpdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/) installed and on the system.  I tried installing via the fink package manager, but according to the package database (http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/qpdf), qpdf doesn't seem to have been built since osx 10.6, and I'm on 10.8.3.

Can anyone point me to qpdf mac install or build instructions?  Or is there a way to disable the warning when checking R packages?

This is somewhat related to the question [qpdf.exe for compactPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738844/qpdf-exe-for-compactpdf), although they were on a windows machine and I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 28):

You can install qpdf with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install qpdf
```

Answer (score 4):

MacPorts can help you. Download MacPorts from http://www.macports.org/ and run `sudo port install qpdf`.

Comment: ping @SimonUrbanek : You might want to solicit opinions on the R-SIG-Mac Mailing List. I know that Simon has expressed concerns about mixing R packages with MacPorts- and Fink-installed packages.